# How to restrict cube access on pentaho bi server 6

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I have been desperately trying to find how  to restrict Mondrain cube access on pentaho BI server 6. Knowing, my schema file is been developped manually (without using the Workbench tool). I have been desperatly been looking for answers every way.

Comment: Please check the server log files after you try to access your cube. There should be a message, which specifies the reason why a user can't access the cube. Attach an excerpt from the log to your question in case you'll need external help. Also, permissions definition from your xml file might be helpful to solve your issue, so paste attach them too.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you have to use the Schema Workbench tool or edit the Mondrian .xml file manually to restrict cube access to certain pre-existing work groups. 
I used this resource from Pentaho to figure out how to create roles to restrict cube access: [Pentaho Mondrian Access Control](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Access_control)

Comment: Hi Jenna, thanks for the reactive response. However after having implemented  role restriction at the bottom line of my schema file (which has several cube definition). i mean the the Xml file to be precise. i then couldn't access the all schema by any user of the systme, whether this on is the admin or any other user. i am pretty sure they're certainly something i am missing some how. And any one helps would million times make a lot more big impact on my daily usage of this system..... thanks to all

Comment: It's actually normal for admin roles to not have access to the cube unless you specifically grant the admin role the right to view the cube. In my use case, all of my users have a general role of "authenticated", and then are broken down in to further authentication groups based on work section,etc. If I say that "authenticated" cannot view the cube, but then give one of the further broken down work sections (Information Systems, for example) permission to view the cube, everyone but the Information Systems department would be blocked from viewing the cube. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also, if you can please attach the log excerpts and other details that user4637357 asked for that would be very helpful to anyone who is trying to assist with this issue.

Comment: Hi Jenna, once again i'am thankful to the kind attention given as much as i am to user4637357. To be more explicit on the reason of my question i have this cube schema .

Comment: <Schema name="Pentaho CE Audit"><Cube name="Pentaho CE Audit" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true"><Table name="PENTAHO_CE_AUDIT">
 </Cube></Schema>

Comment: my aim here is to rend this schema only accessible by the admin User, so i added 


    <Role name="admin">
  <SchemaGrant access="all">
  </SchemaGrant>  
 </Role>

Comment: Before the Schema closing tag. Then i reloaded the file on the system. however after those configuration the cube is not longer accessible neither by the admin or any other users. my question here is to get from you guys the right way forward to set correct criteria on the system in view of restricting access to this cube please.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Two things I noticed: 1) You'll also have to restrict the cube after your schema grant restrictions - see the Pentaho Mondrian Access Control link in my original post. 2) in the code snippet you posted, I see that you are telling in the schema code who CAN see the schema. You also have to tell the schema code who CAN'T see the schema. See next comment...

Comment: Let's say you have another group called "authenticated" that contains all of the active Pentaho users. You would write the code something like this to exclude all of them <Role name="authenticated"> <SchemaGrant access="none"> <CubeGrant access="none"> </CubeGrant> </SchemaGrant> </Role>

Comment: Don't quote me on the structure of that mondrian that I wrote above - usually I use Schema Workbench and don't often "freehand" code like that. Anyway... the takeaway here is that even though you blocked "Authenticated" (all of your active Pentaho users) from viewing the data source and using it, by giving privileges to the Admin group you've allowed "Admin to see the data source and use it without anyone else in the Authenticated group being able to see/use it.

Comment: Jenna i still can't access the cube with your suggestion. i am certainly missing something out. you guys all help is so crucial to me. This is a shoot to all the pentaho users.